# Private attributes in tagged records in Ada

Tags: oop, ada, gnat

Thinking from an object orientated paradigm, how do people tend to implement private attributes for tagged records?

At the moment from what i can see, the only way is to have an attribute that is a private type.

For example

```
type car is tagged record
  i_am_a_public_attribute : Integer;
  i_am_another_public_attribute : Integer;
  my_private_attributes : t_private_attributes;
end record;
```

where t_private_attributes is declared in the private part of the package.

the second way i thought of was to use inheritance, for example

```
type car_public is tagged record
  i_am_a_public_attribute : Integer;
  i_am_another_public_attribute : Integer;
end record;

type car_private is new car_public with record
  my_private_attributes : Integer;
end record;
```

where car_private  was declared in the private part of package. Although this implementation i think would be very messy.

How do people tend to do this?

Thanks Matt

Comment: `type car is tagged private;` and only provide accessors for the public attrs. Stops the unwashed setting your public attrs to negative values for a start...

Answer (score 6):

The private part of a package, in Ada, is closer to a protected in C++, than to a private.
Most of the time, using the private part is the best approach however, and in addition provides the flexibility of writing unit tests as child packages so that they can test the attributes of the type.

If you really want to make the attributes unaccessible to any other part of your code, you have to define them in your body. This can be done with an incomplete type declared in the private part of your package, then completed in the body. Your type would then contain a pointer to this incomplete type, as in:

```
package Foo is
    type My_Type is tagged private;
private
   type Private_Part;
   type Private_Part_Access is access Private_Part;
   type My_Type is tagged record
       P : Private_Part_Access;
   end record;
end Foo;
package body Foo is
   type Private_Part is record
      ...
   end record;
end Foo;
```

This could be done also by making Private_Part an abstract tagged null record, and extend it in the body.

The difficulty with this scheme, of course, is memory management since you have to make sure your object will indeed free the corresponding memory (perhaps through the use of controlled types).

Answer (score 2):

This is an expansion of what Brian Drummond wrote in the comment above. When I do OOP in the Ada programming language and wish to express the idea of a "class" with some private and public attributes, I would write (using Matt's example):

```
type Car_Type is tagged private;

function I_Am_A_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type)       return Integer;
function I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type) return Integer;

private

type Car_Type is tagged
   record
      I_Am_A_Public_Attribute        : Integer;
      I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute  : Integer;
      I_Am_A_Private_Attribute       : Integer;
      I_Am_Another_Private_Attribute : Integer;
   end record;

function I_Am_A_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type)       return Integer is (This.I_Am_A_Public_Attribute);
function I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type) return Integer is (This.I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute);
```

The idea is to have a get-function for each attribute that one wants to be public. Actually, the code above is not what I would call "Ada style". To take advantage of the strength of Ada, define a new type for each attribute:

```
type I_Am_A_Public_Attribute_Type        is new Integer;
type I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute_Type  is new Integer;

type Car_Type is tagged private;

function I_Am_A_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type)       return I_Am_A_Public_Attribute_Type;
function I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type) return I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute_Type;

private

type I_Am_A_Private_Attribute_Type       is new Integer;
type I_Am_Another_Private_Attribute_Type is new Integer;

type Car_Type is tagged
   record
      I_Am_A_Public_Attribute        : I_Am_A_Public_Attribute_Type;
      I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute  : I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute_Type;
      I_Am_A_Private_Attribute       : I_Am_A_Private_Attribute_Type;
      I_Am_Another_Private_Attribute : I_Am_Another_Private_Attribute_Type;
   end record;

function I_Am_A_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type)       return I_Am_A_Public_Attribute_Type        is (This.I_Am_A_Public_Attribute);
function I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute (This : Car_Type) return I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute_Type  is (This.I_Am_Another_Public_Attribute);
```

Pay attention to that if one mixes a get-function with the wrong attribute one will get a compile-time error. This is a good example of "Ada, in strong typing we trust".

**EDIT:** Once I investigated if there is from a performance perspective any preference on the choice between public attributes and get-functions. I found that there was no difference in performance when using the GNAT compiler. I have not tried that same experiment with any other compiler.