# Create a record with a private part

Tags: ada, gnat

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25890147), I'v try to do a record with a private part. What I've done :

MyFile.ads :

```
package MyPackage is
  type T_MyType is tagged private;
private
  type T_MyType_Private_Part;
  type T_MyType_Private_Part_Access is access T_MyType_Pirvate_Part;
  type T_MyType is tagged record
    Toto : Boolean;
  end record
end MyPackage;
```

MyFile.adb :

```
package body MyPackage is
   type T_MyType_Private_Part is record
     Private_Toto : Boolean;
   end record
end MyPackage;
```

But when an other package do `MyVar.Toto` where `MyVar` is `T_MyType` I have the error :

> no selector "Toto" for type "T_MyType" defined at MyFile.ads

How can I fix this ?

Comment: As your type T_MyType is private, you can't access anything inside the private part. You'll have to provide subprograms to deal with Toto. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Packages#The_private_part

Comment: I don't know what "a record with a private part" means (Ada records don't have private parts), but as it says in [_Ada Distilled_](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/distilled/adadistilled.pdf), "Understanding visibility is the key to understanding Ada," and "Some programmers find the concept of visibility more difficult than any other part of Ada. Once they really understand visibility, everything else in [the] language makes sense." This is a misunderstanding of Ada's visibility rules, so you need to familiarize yourself with them.

Comment: The other package can't see Toto - precisely because you made it private. The other package can only use operations published by MyPackage (defined in its public part) to interact with Toto (but so far, there aren't any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple to produce a record with a private part using Ada.

The following example declares a base tagged type with a public member. It then creates a child package which extends the tagged type with private members. The type declared in the child package has both a public and private data members.

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package base_type is
   type base is tagged record
      Name : Unbounded_String;
   end record;
end base_type;
```

The package named base_type declares a tagged record with a public member. The

```ada
package base_type.person is
   type gender is (male, female);
   type weights is new Float range 0.0 .. 500.0;

   type person_type is new base with private;

   procedure set_gender (P : in out person_type; G : in gender);
   procedure set_weight (P : in out person_type; W : in weights);
   procedure Print (P : person_type);

private
   type person_type is new base with record
      G : gender;
      W : weights;
   end record;

end base_type.person;
```

The body of base_type.person is

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body base_type.person is

   ----------------
   -- set_gender --
   ----------------

   procedure set_gender (P : in out person_type; G : in gender) is
   begin
      P.G := G;
   end set_gender;

   ----------------
   -- set_weight --
   ----------------

   procedure set_weight (P : in out person_type; W : in weights) is
   begin
      P.W := W;
   end set_weight;

   -----------
   -- Print --
   -----------

   procedure Print (P : person_type) is
      package w_io is new Float_IO(weights);
      use w_io;
   begin
      Put_Line(To_String(P.Name));
      Put_Line ("Gender: " & P.G'Image);
      Put("Weight: ");
      Put(Item => P.W, Fore => 1, aft => 1, Exp => 0);
      New_Line(2);
   end Print;

end base_type.person;
```

A should be expected, the private data members may only be accessed through procedures and functions.

A main procedure creating a program example is

```ada
with base_type.person;      use base_type.person;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure Main is
   P1 : person_type;
   P2 : person_type;
begin
   P1.set_gender (Male);
   P1.set_weight (165.2);
   P1.Name := To_Unbounded_String ("Barney Rubble");
   P2.Name := To_Unbounded_String ("Betty Rubble");
   P2.set_gender (female);
   P2.set_weight (110.5);
   Print (P1);
   Print (P2);
end Main;
```

The output of this program is:

```text
Barney Rubble
Gender: MALE
Weight: 165.2

Betty Rubble
Gender: FEMALE
Weight: 110.5
```